# Importing data into Quickbooks Online with their API

Tags: api-design, quickbooks-online

I am looking to build an app for QB. I have a small accounting service which I would like the transactions and invoices to be imported into quickbooks. It looks like I could create customers, payments, and invoices as they are entered into my service, but I am wondering if there's an option to have this information passed to quickbooks via a webhook. Similar to how their bank import pulls in data when you hit refresh, is there a way we can hook in similar apps?

Comment: What, if anything, have you already tried? If you've tried anything, please edit your question to include your code/setup thus far, because it might provide a good start point for a solution.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm working in NodeJs and looks like there's a decent wrapper for the API. Every time I edit / delete / add something into my system, I'm also going to have to do my own saving in database as well as update the client's QBO account. What I'm wondering is there any way QBO can update the data it's looking for in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, QuickBooks does not support what you're looking for (the ability to have QuickBooks poll a URL for new data).

Intuit's developer site is at the link below. You should review their documentation below:

https://developer.intuit.com/

Comment: I've been looking through their docs and I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have fully integrated the QBO API into our systems and we're able to synchronize transactions, invoices and customers without a problem. It's hard to discern from your question exactly what direction the information would be flowing.

Through the API you can create, read, update, delete and query Invoices, Payments and much more. You are right that you can create customers, payments and invoices when they're created in your system but you're wondering if there is an option to have this passed "passed to quickbooks via webhook."

QuickBooks Online does not have any *inbound* webhooks, but if information is going *in to* QuickBooks, those functions aren't passed into QuickBooks via a webhook but they are passed in through API calls.

If you are seeking to have QuickBooks Online call your service via an *outbound* webhook when something is updated, this is now possible. [See this blog post for more details on Webhooks for QBO API](https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2016/07/19/webhooks-quickbooks-online-api).

Before they rolled out *outbound* webhooks, we had built a cron job service to poll QuickBooks for any changes but now we utilize the webhooks to trigger instant updates *to* our system without having to poll QuickBooks.